# List directories in Windows Azure Blob storage container

Tags: c#, azure, directory, containers

I have a question about my project... I need to know how to list all folders (in a string list or something) from a Windows Azure blob storage... I allready have my BlobClient and the connection to my Azure storage.

Who can help me with this "problem"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this code. It makes use of **Storage Client library 2.0.3**:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("wad-control-container");
        string blobPrefix = null;
        bool useFlatBlobListing = false;
        var blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs(blobPrefix, useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails.None);
        var folders = blobs.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
        }
```

If you're using **Storage Client Library 1.8 (i.e. previous to version 2.0)**, try this code:

```
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("wad-control-container");
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = container.ListBlobs(new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            UseFlatBlobListing = false,
        });
        var folders = blobs.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null);

        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
        }
```

Comment: I get a "No overload for method 'ListBlobs' takes 3 arguments" error. and "blobContainer.ListBlobs(blobPrefix, useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails.None");" is red underlined.

Comment: This is probably because you're using an older version of the library. I have modified my answer above to show code for both libraries.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't get it why it still doesn't work... This is what i have at the moment. The signature string is filled by my service for a SAS connect to my Azure blob storage. This is a screenshot of my code: [link](http://cindesbetondesign.nl/1.png)

Comment: Looking at your code, I see that first you create a cloud blob client using SAS URL (which is correct) but then you recreate the same object with a connection to development storage and then you're using the 2nd object to fetch the list of blob folders. Could that be the reason? It would help if you post the entire code as part of your question so that any issues with the code can be identified. Also please tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: `The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.` Is the error

Comment: It could be because of many things. First it may be because of the code issue I noted above in my comment. It could also be because the blob container does not exist in the storage account or there may be an issue with the shared access signature in the sense that it has expired. If the SAS URL does not expose any sensitive information, it would help if you could post the SAS URL you're using.

Comment: and i have changed the "recreation" of the same object.

Comment: My SAS works correctly because i can upload files through my SAS key so I think the problem must be something different...

Comment: Yes it has the right prermissions `string signature = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write | SharedAccessPermissions.Read
            });`

Comment: Instead of using DateTime.Now, please try DateTime.UtcNow as everything in Windows Azure is in UTC.

Comment: Okay, i have changed that time parameter

Comment: And my Base URI from my BlobClient is: "http://ferryjongmans.blob.core.windows.net/filiaal4455" The URL is correct and the container exists in this storage..

Comment: (Kicking myself for not seeing it sooner :))! I think I know why you're running into this problem. For listing blobs in a blob container, you need to have "List" permission in your shared access signature instead of "Read" permission. Try this: string signature = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy() { SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write | SharedAccessPermissions.List });

Comment: NB: You need to have a file in a directory for it to show. Empty directories are not listed.

Comment: Code can be dramatically simplified. The arguments like UseFlatBlobListing provided are the defaults. So this is equivalent to the example above: `var folders = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>().ToList();` If you want just the folder names: `var folderNames = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>().Select(i => i.Prefix).ToList();`

Answer (score 4):

I've used this solution in my project

```
// Retrieve reference to the container.
CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(lvContainer.SelectedItems[0].Text);

//Loop over VIRTUAL directories within the container
foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs())
{
      if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
      {
           CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
           string[] uri = directory.Uri.ToString().Split('/');
           ListViewItem dir = new ListViewItem();
           dir.Text = uri[uri.Length-2];
           dir.ImageIndex = 0;

           ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
           subitem.Text = String.Empty; //item.Properties.LastModifiedUtc.ToString();
           dir.SubItems.Add(subitem);

           subitem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
           subitem.Text = String.Empty; //item.Properties.Length + " bytes";
           dir.SubItems.Add(subitem);

           lvBlob.Items.Add(dir);
       }
}
```

In my case I was displaying the results in a listView, listing size and date, using

```
(item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
```

and

```
(item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
```

in the same foreach to list every layer of virtual folders, BlockBlobs and PageBlobs differently.
Hope this helps.